# Given is a density.. Determine a method of moment for $\lambda$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, discrete-mathematics

> $X_1,..,X_n$ are observations of a population with density
>   $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left\{\begin{matrix} \lambda e^{\lambda x}
> \;\,\text{ if } x<0\\  \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \text{ if } x \geq 0
> \end{matrix}\right.$
>
> where parameter $\lambda$ is unknown. Determine a moment of moment
>   (estimation) for $\lambda$.

**Edit: I tried to answer my question with help of the given comments, see it below**

I don't think they ask question like this in exam but I find it on internet and want know how example can be done correct?

How I understand is you need to calculate the expected value of the density function:
$$E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \cdot f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{1}{2} x \cdot \lambda e^{\lambda x}dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} x \cdot \lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx \\ = \left[\frac{(\lambda x-1)e^{\lambda x}}{2\lambda}\right]_{-\infty}^{0} + \left[-\frac{(\lambda x+1)e^{-\lambda x}}{2\lambda}\right]_{0}^{\infty} = \\ = \left[\frac{(\lambda \cdot 0-1)e^{\lambda \cdot 0}}{2\lambda} - \left(\frac{(\lambda \cdot (-\infty)-1)e^{\lambda \cdot (-\infty)}}{2\lambda}\right)\right]+ \\ +\left[-\frac{(\lambda \cdot \infty+1)e^{-\lambda \cdot \infty}}{2\lambda} - \left(-\frac{(\lambda \cdot 0+1)e^{-\lambda \cdot 0}}{2\lambda}\right)\right] = \\ = \left[-\frac{1}{2\lambda}-\left(\frac{-\infty \cdot 0}{2\lambda}\right)\right]+ \left[-\frac{0}{2\lambda}-\left(-\frac{1}{2\lambda}\right)\right] = \\ = \left[-\frac{1}{2\lambda}-0\right] + \left[0+\frac{1}{2\lambda}\right] = -\frac{1}{2\lambda}+\frac{1}{2\lambda}=0$$

Very frustrating after this long way all I get is zero..? :(

Is this complete wrong way of doing it? Because I don't think I do the calculation wrong at least.

Comment: Without any computations, just note that the distribution is symmetric: $f(x)=f(-x)=\frac{1}{2}\lambda e^{-\lambda|x|}$, and thus the mean must be zero.

Comment: @Shalop Thank you this is very good to know! Can you also tell me if that was the correct way to get a method of moment / estimation for $\lambda$? Because in the end I didn't even get a value for $\lambda$ :p

Comment: The first moment is independent of $\lambda$, so you need to try to use the second moment condition to compute the MOM estimator.

Comment: @BGM Can you give a little more impulse pls so I can try it :)

Comment: @BGM By second moment you mean the variance? So I calculate the variance and by doing so I will get the MOM estimator?

Comment: It may help to know that this is a [_Laplace_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) distribution with location parameter $\mu = 0$ and scale parameter $b = 1/\lambda.$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics) The moment equation, traditionally is referring to the moment but not the central moment, although $Var[X] = E[X^2]$ in this case as $E[X] = 0$. The moment equation you need is $\displaystyle E[X^2] = \frac {1} {n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$

Comment: @BGM Thank you for hints I try solve it with your help I answer my question below because it was very long for comment and when I edit my question your comment maybe confuse other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have tried to solve this again with your help (comments):

We already calculated the first moment which is $E(X) = 0$

The second moment I solve on paper with long calculation, just assume it's correct: $E(X^2) = \frac{2}{\lambda^2}$

Thus the sample first moment is $\bar{x}= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ and the sample second moment is $\bar{x''}= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2$

$$E(X) = \bar{x} \Leftrightarrow 0 = \bar{x}$$

$$E(X^2) = \bar{x''} \Leftrightarrow \frac{2}{\lambda^2}= \bar{x''} \Leftrightarrow \frac{\lambda^2}{2} = \frac{1}{\bar{x''}} \Leftrightarrow \lambda^2= \frac{2}{\bar{x''}} \Leftrightarrow \lambda = ^{+}_{-}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\bar{x''}}}$$

Therefore we have method of moment estimation $$\lambda_1= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\bar{x''}}} \text{ and } \lambda_2 = -\sqrt{\frac{2}{\bar{x''}}}$$

I hope this is alright now?